# AWS S3 - request has multiple authentication types, please use one

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I want to upload a file by AWS,
I get a Pre Signed Url in .NetCore by Key and SecretKey...

[image]

And then I use this URL in Angular to upload my file :

[image]

But I got this error as a result :

**Invalid Request (request has multiple authentication types, please use one)**

you can see the request details in the below images :

**Haeders :**

[image]

**Payload:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing remove the key from your request, and only use the one with the client.

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Looks like you didn't indicate an [HTTP verb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/THttpVerb.html), so your pre-signed URL is GET and cannot be used for uploading. Request a PUT URL in your request and issue a PUT request. The .Net SDK may also support an option to create a pre-signed POST URL with custom policy (other SDKs do), but I can't immediately locate this in the .Net SDK docs.

Comment: Here's the [S3PostUploadRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/S3/TS3PostUploadRequest.html).

Comment: Also, the key that you supply when creating these request objects is the key of the S3 object (e.g. `dogs/snoopy.png`), not your credentials access key (e.g. `AKIAEXAMPLE`).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is you are not calling the correct S3 operation. To generate a Presigned URL that you can use to upload an object - you need to call **presignPutObject()** - not **presignGetObject()**.

Once you get back the URL from presignPutObject(), you can use that to upload an object to an Amazon S3 bucket. We have that exact use case using a React app in this example here:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/cross_PAM_java_2_topic.html)

Comment: thanks, @smac2020 for ur response, but actually I use .NetCore and I call GetPreSignedUrl(), Not presignPutObject or presignGetObject.